# Simplest way to "decal" in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, rendering, mesh, decal

This is all done in C++ with GLSL...

I have mesh A.  I project another (flat) mesh onto mesh A, and it takes the shape of the part of Mesh A it collides with.  This is how I'm putting decals onto a model.

Now, I used a seperate shader to render the decal's pixels.  Without going too deep into it, I prevent z-fighting and put the decal on top by simply multiplying the final vertex position's "w" by 1.0005f.  This seems to work with everything I throw at it.

The only downside is, when very, very, very zoomed in, you can see that the decal is hovering above mesh A (because it is).  Is there some better way for me to do this decal deal?  Rendering it multitexture is not an option because of the application involved-- it has to be a seperate mesh.  Is there some better method of adjusting w than a multiply like this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `glPolygonOffset` ([official documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml)). This applies an offset to the depth only and not the actual position of the vertex.